# How do you use a JSON API in PHP on Wordpress?

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api, associative-array

Here my url address for https://goalserve.com/getfeed/mytoken/topscorers/1204?json=1

How can I get the "player" data, I want to use make "top scorers standing widget" on my PHP Wordpress site.

```json
{
    "?xml":{
        "@version":"1.0",
        "@encoding":"utf-8"
    },
    "topscorers":{
        "@sport":"soccer",
        "tournament":{
            "@name":"Premier League",
            "@stage_id":"12041081",
            "@gid":"1204",
            "@is_current":"True",
            "@id":"1204",
            "player":[
                {
                    "@pos":"1",
                    "@name":"Mohamed Salah",
                    "@team":"Liverpool",
                    "@team_id":"9249",
                    "@goals":"15",
                    "@penalty_goals":"2",
                    "@id":"138653"
                },
                {
                    "@pos":"2",
                    "@name":"Diogo Jota",
                    "@team":"Liverpool",
                    "@team_id":"9249",
                    "@goals":"10",
                    "@penalty_goals":"0",
                    "@id":"374031"
                },
                {
                    "@pos":"3",
                    "@name":"J. Vardy",
                    "@team":"Leicester City",
                    "@team_id":"9240",
                    "@goals":"9",
                    "@penalty_goals":"0",
                    "@id":"159732"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried call API with https://goalserve.com/getfeed/mytoken/topscorers/1204?json=1, but show only 2 data from  "?xml" and "topscorers". How can I get the "player" section because it under "topscorers" -> "tournament".

Comment: Are you trying to do it on the client or server side

Comment: I have no idea about client or server side. I tried to get the "player" for foreach loop,  which I do it now is stil stuck foreach for "?xml" and "topscorers" data.

Comment: Are you using javascript or php?

Comment: I'm using PHP...

Comment: Here my code for the wordpress widget https://ibb.co/j5H0pBw

Comment: Please use something like https://gist.github.com/ to share code snippets

Comment: PHP is processed server side. You have to select `topscorers` -> `tournament` -> `player` and set that equal to `$players`.  Then do a `foreach ($palyers as $p)` to iterate over them.  Inside the for loop you could then do something like: `$html .= '<span> . $p->name . '</span>';`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/adamsari404/23f9e27690fd38e17c3fe65958b33595

I have no idea how to implement the parse json with php.

Comment: You already did it with the function `json_decode`.  That takes the json string and turns it into a php object.  You then have to drill down into the object to get the data you want.

Comment: How to select topscorers -> tournament -> player, I still have no clue to drill down into the data I want. I tried read some tutorial, but still stuck.

Comment: So there are a few ways to do it.  I provided an example and in it I used `$value = $hash_table->{'key'};` to get the job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

To do this you must first decode the json string into a php object.  Then you must drill down to the proper data that you want.  You can do this with the `->` operator like so:

```php
$players = json_decode($raw_string)->{'topscorers'}->{'tournament'}->{'player'};
```

Note that you should save the result of the decoded json string if you plan on reusing the data.  Don't decode it more than once.

After you have the players, you can then iterate over the data and do what you want with it.  Here is a minimal example with your data so you can see it all working together.

## Example

### Dataset

```php
<?php

$raw_string = '
{
    "?xml":{
        "@version":"1.0",
        "@encoding":"utf-8"
    },
    "topscorers":{
        "@sport":"soccer",
        "tournament":{
            "@name":"Premier League",
            "@stage_id":"12041081",
            "@gid":"1204",
            "@is_current":"True",
            "@id":"1204",
            "player":[
                {
                    "@pos":"1",
                    "@name":"Mohamed Salah",
                    "@team":"Liverpool",
                    "@team_id":"9249",
                    "@goals":"15",
                    "@penalty_goals":"2",
                    "@id":"138653"
                },
                {
                    "@pos":"2",
                    "@name":"Diogo Jota",
                    "@team":"Liverpool",
                    "@team_id":"9249",
                    "@goals":"10",
                    "@penalty_goals":"0",
                    "@id":"374031"
                },
                {
                    "@pos":"3",
                    "@name":"J. Vardy",
                    "@team":"Leicester City",
                    "@team_id":"9240",
                    "@goals":"9",
                    "@penalty_goals":"0",
                    "@id":"159732"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}';
?>
```

### Processing

```php
<?php
$php_object = json_decode($raw_string);
$players = $php_object->{'topscorers'}->{'tournament'}->{'player'};

$html = '';
$html .= '<table>';
$html .= '<tr>';
$html .= '<td>Pos</td>';
$html .= '<td>Player</td>';
$html .= '<td>Team</td>';
$html .= '<td>Goals</td>';
$html .= '</tr>';


foreach ($players as $p) {
  $html .= '<tr>';
  $html .= '<td>' . $p->{'@pos'}   . '</td>';
  $html .= '<td>' . $p->{'@name'}  . '</td>';
  $html .= '<td>' . $p->{'@team'}  . '</td>';
  $html .= '<td>' . $p->{'@goals'} . '</td>';
  $html .= '</tr>';
}

$html .= '</table>';

echo($html);

?>
```

### Output

```html
<table><tr><td>Pos</td><td>Player</td><td>Team</td><td>Goals</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>Mohamed Salah</td><td>Liverpool</td><td>15</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>Diogo Jota</td><td>Liverpool</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>J. Vardy</td><td>Leicester City</td><td>9</td></tr></table>
```

| Pos | Player | Team | Goals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mohamed Salah | Liverpool | 15 |
| 2 | Diogo Jota | Liverpool | 10 |
| 3 | J. Vardy | Leicester City | 9 |

Comment: Great!! You saved my life, I have tried this issues for an hours. Thank you very much.